# Make all commands obey symbolic link directory hierarchy

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, autocomplete

At least in bash, by default, the option `set +P` is set, which makes certain commands like `cd`, `pwd`, and tab-completion follow the symbolic link hierarchy, rather than the physical hierarchy.  But, lots of other commands, like `ls`, just follow the physical hierarchy.

You can do `set -P` to make all commands follow the physical directory structure (or add it to your `~/.inputrc` file for permanence across sessions).  But, what if I want to go the other way, to make all (most?) commands obey the symbolic directory structure?  Can this be done?  Is this bash-specific?  Alternatively, is there a way to make things believe the symbolic directory **is** physical?  And to be clear, I'm looking for a setting to affect behavior across all potential functions, not a workaround like `readlink`.  The closest I can find is [this workaround](https://superuser.com/a/1217241/237182).

For an example of how one can get unpleasant results, keep reading.  This can lead to confusing behavior since you can tab-complete to a file/folder that the command you're running won't be able to find.  For instance (you might have to do `set +P` first):

```
mkdir symtest1
mkdir symtest1/subdir
ln -s symtest1/subdir
touch youreinthebasedir         #a lovely file to show where you're looking
touch symtest1/youreinsymtest1  #yet another
pwd                             #shows where you are
cd subdir
pwd                             #should show the same plus "/subdir"
ls ../                          #should show the contents of "symtest1"
```

Now, type the following with tab-completion, 
`ls ../youre`<kbd>tab</kbd>
and it'll complete to 
`../youreinthebasedir`
but hit enter, and you'll get an error that the file doesn't exist due to the aforementioned discrepancy.

Some more useful discussion can be found [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/symbolic-links-to-directories-mystery-898683/) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/151457/237182).

Comment: Note: POSIX defines [*parent directory*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_268) as `the directory that both contains a directory entry for the given directory and is represented by the pathname dot-dot in the given directory`. Also [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13): `The special filename dot-dot shall refer to the parent directory of its predecessor directory`. A symlink is not "a directory entry for the given directory", so your shell interprets `..` against POSIX; `ls` does it "right".

Comment: Oh, the above comment is not meant to discredit the question. Your question is fine, I have upvoted it. I'm just giving some context and rationale.

Comment: "Alternatively, is there a way to make things believe the symbolic directory is physical?" – You may find this interesting: [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/108618)